# How to filter page content according to dropdown box selection in cakephp 2.x

Tags: ajax, select, filter, cakephp-2.0

I have a select box in my view.ctp , it shows some content from the controller, but my problem is i want to load content dynamically according to the droapdown selection
i tried with making ajax request on onchange of selection in the select box. but  the problem is ,the select box id is sending to the controller function, their i set the content for display .but the page is not refreshing..
I dont know which logic sholud use for this purpose..if anybody have an exerience with this..please replay me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve those results you should follow the next steps:

1. Create an action that returns the content with $this->layout = null
2. Create a view for this action that displays the content in the way you desire (html with no css)
3. In the view that you like to fetch that content through AJAX make a request that pulls that controller and view
4. append it where you want it on your page (with proper css on the page you make the request it will display correctly)

Comment: You can have two controller and two views OR one controller which discards the layout when data is sent through POST. Many other solutions are available, depending on what you like to accomplish. I generally avoid code redundancy and like to have an action which responds with a list of objects depending on the conditions I send, this way I can use it in multiple places. Eg. short list of products, you have one on first page, one depending on category and so on. I don't make an action with find in each one, i have one listView, that I call with conditions!

Comment: thanx for your reply.the past day i struggled a lot for finding the solution.. thax again. can u post one simple example for this , it will help all...

Comment: please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440905/making-jquery-ajax-call-from-view-to-controller-in-cakephp-2-x