# send data from cakephp view to controller using $.ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am using $.ajax for the first time in CakePhp2.4.5- I read a lot of Posts on stackoverflow and did other research on w3schools and jquery site but could not understand how should I solve my problem.
I want to send data to the Controller from my 1st view index.ctp

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'meers/client',
                datatype:'json',
                cache: false,
                data: {myVal:'Success!'},
                success: function(){alert('AjaX Success')},
                error: function(){alert('AjaX Failed')}
            })
                .done(function(){
                    alert('AjaX Done!');
                });
```

alert show 'AjaX Success'.

in my Controller I have

`public function client(){
if($this->request->isAjax()){
            $this->set('ajaxTest','Success');
        }}`

in my SECOND view client.ctp I have.

`if(isset($ajaxTest)){
    echo $ajaxTest;
}else{
    echo 'ajaxTest not Set.';
}`

PROBLEM. I always get msg in my Client.ctp view "ajaxTest not Set".
What am I doing wrong ? or How to Do it ? Thanks

Comment: How you getting this "ajaxTest not Set"? via firebug or by using direct url?

Comment: you can see in my View client.ctp I have an if statement if $ajaxTest is set or not.

Comment: I'm not a CakePHP developer, but shouldn't you use `is('ajax')` instead of the `isAjax`? It seems [the second syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request) is deprecated. Please note that JavaScript is case-sensitive, the `datatype` property should be `dataType`.

Comment: @undefined even if I remove this isAjax thing shouldn't it work ? It doesn't. I never get data in my Controller I tried in many different ways. I removed this if statement and put it like this.
$this->set('ajaxTest',$this->request->myVal);
never get a value passed to ajaxTest variable that I send to client view.

Comment: If the "alert show 'AjaX Success'", then how do you know the response text of the request? Does this mean that you see `'ajaxTest not Set.'` for non-ajax request or you debug the request in the browser's console?

Comment: I check only in my view. I explain the process how I do it.
1. I click on a div in my first view index.ctp it fires the $.ajax thing and as I think it it sends a variable named myVal to the Controller where I have to catch it and process it.
2. In controller I set the variable with $this->set('ajaxTest') and pass it to my view.
3. In my 2nd view client.ctp I check if variable ajaxTest is set 
4. It fails

Answer (score 2):

i think that you problem is in the url because 'meers/client' in not a route

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'YourController','action' => 'YourAction')); ?>",
        datatype:'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {myVal:'Success!'},
        success: function(){alert('AjaX Success')},
        error: function(){alert('AjaX Failed')}
    })
        .done(function(){
            alert('AjaX Done!');
        });
```

or can probe giving a router:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourAction'), true); ?>",
        datatype:'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {myVal:'Success!'},
        success: function(){alert('AjaX Success')},
        error: function(){alert('AjaX Failed')}
    })
        .done(function(){
            alert('AjaX Done!');
        });
```

you can see other examples:

http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/

[Making jquery ajax call from view to controller in cakephp 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440905/making-jquery-ajax-call-from-view-to-controller-in-cakephp-2-x)

Comment: @#Widrogo thanks for your reply but if I give this function a false route it should give an error as I have tried by giving a false url. But in my code the AjaX returns a SUCCESS. What about it ?

Comment: I used your version of URL but it gave me this error in console
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
and what i have found is Html Helper is now including my root App name in the Url /MyAppName/meers/client , I think it is not accessable.

Comment: make a debug in you controller debug($this->request->isAjax()); and for do a request Depends on the version of cake.
1.3.x:
$this->ResquestHandler->isAjax();
2.x
$this->request->is('ajax');

Comment: I have mentioned my cakephp version in the post it is 2.4.5 and what about the URL ? should I keep the way it is ? I am going to check debug and ->is('ajax'). by the way what if I leave the if statement for checking if it is ajax ? I want first of all see data in controller coming from ajax post.

Comment: see in your code you need see 1 the url 2 your request according to version. now is a little difficult to write and revise your code in me phone, I will help you more when I get my pc. while searching in google about this

Comment: I have already checked $this->request->is('ajax') it didnt work and for the URL I commented over that it gives an error while it adds my app name in the url like /myAppName/meers/client. You can write code later just tell me I will try it and if your suggestion works You can later edit the answer.

Comment: my be it helps you to find the PROBLEM. I have TWO VIEWS 1. index.ctp here I have $.ajax and it send POST request to meersController and there I set a variable and pass it to another view 2. client.ctp. Now When I click on a div in VIEW index.ctp it send Post to meersController where the variable is set and sent to the client.ctp in background. now I open /meers/client in browser and I see that the meersController didn't set the variable. DID YOU GET MY POINT ?

Comment: One thing MORE. I dont want any data back in my FIRST VIEW index.ctp. I just want to send data to the meersController to manipulate.

Comment: ok I understand but that show this: debug($this->request->isAjax());  is a debug I want to see that. Because the first you need know is your data go to the controller. this debug display the result in your view (client.ctp) of his controller clientController

Comment: Ok I try it and tell you in 30sec what happened.

Comment: is false because it is not getting anything, now why is not getting anything?, may be the url, or an error in the code (I think not) in your cakephp debugkit you notice that reach client.ctp varibles. My suggestion as I said in the beginning I think this in the url

Comment: my variable reach client.ctp as when I set $this->set->('myVar','Success!'); I get this value displayed in my client.ctp and if in the $.ajax call I type url:'meer123345/client' it give me an error that mean url:'meer/client' not giving an error so it is working. is it not so ?