# Can't access element using its new id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am triyng to acces an elemet using its new atribute.

HTML

```
<div class="element">Element1</div>
```

The script is

```
$('.element').one("click", function() 
{
    $.getScript('/script.js');
});  

$('#activated').click(function() 
{
    alert(1);
});
```

Inside the script.js file :

```
$('.element').attr("id", "activated");
```

The script.js adds the id #activated to the div, but .click() won't work using the new id.

Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: That's because you probably run `$('#activated').click(...` in `$(document).ready(...` and since you dynamically insert the `activated` id it is not there until you click the `element` div, which will happen long after `$(document).ready(...` has executed. So `$('#activated')` will not be found.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen, yes, the script was running in $(document).ready, but i removed it, and still the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#activated')` is evaluated before any element has that id, so it finds no elements, and no click handlers are attached to any elements.

You can use event delegation to work around this. A click handler will be attached to the document body immediately, but it will only trigger its callback if the target element matches the '#activated' selector:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#activated', function() 
{
    alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the line `$('#activated').click(function()` is executed, there is no element with ID of `activated` in the document, so jQuery returns an empty collection and `click` method silently fails. You can either use the event delegation technique:

```
$(document).on('click', '#activated', function()
```

or check the id of the clicked element in your first event handler:

```
$('.element').on("click", function() 
{
    if ( this.id === 'activated' ) 
    {
       // ...
    } 
    else 
    {
       $.getScript('/script.js');
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that with the second method, `$.getScript('/script.js');` can be executed more than once if the button is clicked multiple times before script.js has loaded once. (If script.js's effect is idempotent, then that could be a useful feature: if it fails to load the first time, then the user can click the button again to try to load the script again.)

Comment: Thank you for the code and explication! Your code works!

Comment: @AgentME Yes, that's true, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

try `$(document).on('click','#activated',function(){ // do somthing here });` it might work. Tell me it doesnt.

Comment: `click` method calls the `on` method behind the scenes, so effectively it doesn't make a difference, if you want to delegate the event, another version of `on` method should be used.

Comment: @undefined: and now ?

Comment: @undefined I have a question and I have not found an answer even after as much research as possible and I am also not getting any answer please if you can help you have good reputation. Question is here ---> Please Help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306067/send-data-from-cakephp-view-to-controller-using-ajax-post?noredirect=1#comment41281361_26306067